# How to get Socket ID in Jmeter?

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io, jmeter

I refer to this tutorial
: http://seleniumparadise.blogspot.com/2015/07/jmeter-web-socket-testing.html

I am trying to test web socket but it cannot run `HTTP` Request.

[image]

My WebSocket :

```
ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=DemHDCauiFttdm0WAAA9
```

How to get Socket ID in my web socket ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can test WebSocket protocol using HTTP Request sampler and would recommend using [WebSocket Sampler plugin](https://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter-WebSocketSampler) instead. The easiest way to install the plugin is using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: WebSocket Protocol support]

Comment: How to get Socket ID using WebSocket Sampler ?
: http://i.imgur.com/NUki05e.png

Thanks for your answer.